# Sparksql Pyspark crossJoin over dimension / for a specific window

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is my data frame

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("A", "2018-01-05"), ("A", "2018-02-10"), ("B", "2018-08-11"), ("B", "2018-09-11")], ("ID", "date"))
```

I'd like to transform it so it looks like this:

```
+---+----------+----------+
| ID|     date1|     date2|
+---+----------+----------+
|  A|2018-01-05|2018-02-10|
|  A|2018-02-10|2018-01-05|
|  A|2018-01-05|2018-01-05|
|  A|2018-02-10|2018-02-10|
|  B|2018-08-11|2018-09-11|
|  B|2018-09-11|2018-08-11|
|  B|2018-08-11|2018-08-11|
|  B|2018-09-11|2018-09-11|
+---+----------+----------+
```

So basically I need to do a crossJoin but only for the values associated with a specific ID. Is this possible? Any ideas? Maybe through a window function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is

```
df.join(df, ["ID"]).toDF("id", "date1", "date2").show()
```

And the result is

```
+---+----------+----------+                                                     
| id|     date1|     date2|
+---+----------+----------+
|  B|2018-08-11|2018-08-11|
|  B|2018-08-11|2018-09-11|
|  B|2018-09-11|2018-08-11|
|  B|2018-09-11|2018-09-11|
|  A|2018-01-05|2018-01-05|
|  A|2018-01-05|2018-02-10|
|  A|2018-02-10|2018-01-05|
|  A|2018-02-10|2018-02-10|
+---+----------+----------+
```